# Multiple textures doesn't show

Tags: texture2d, directx-10

I'm a newbie of DirectX10. Now I'm developing a Direct10 application. It mixes two textures which are filled manually according to user's input. The current implementation is

1. Create two empty textures with usage D3D10_USAGE_STAGING.
2. Create two resource shader view to bind to the pixel shader because the shader needs it.
3. Copy the textures to the GPU memory by calling CopyResource.

Now the problem is that I can only see the first texture but I don't see the second. It looks to me that the binding doesn't work for the second texture.

I don't know what's wrong with it. Can anyone here shed me a light on it?

Thanks,
Marshall

The class COverlayTexture takes responsible for creating the texture, creating resource view, fill the texture with the mapped bitmap from another applicaiton and bind the resource view to the pixel shader.

```
HRESULT COverlayTexture::Initialize(VOID)
{
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesStaging;
texDesStaging.Width = m_width;
texDesStaging.Height = m_height;
texDesStaging.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_STAGING;
texDesStaging.BindFlags = 0;
texDesStaging.ArraySize = 1;
texDesStaging.MipLevels = 1;
texDesStaging.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesStaging.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texDesStaging.MiscFlags = 0;
texDesStaging.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
texDesStaging.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;  
HR( m_Device->CreateTexture2D( &texDesStaging, NULL, &m_pStagingResource ) );

D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesShader;
texDesShader.Width = m_width;
texDesShader.Height = m_height;
texDesShader.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
texDesShader.ArraySize = 1;
texDesShader.MipLevels = 1;
texDesShader.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesShader.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texDesShader.MiscFlags = 0;    
texDesShader.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
texDesShader.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;    
texDesShader.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
HR( m_Device->CreateTexture2D( &texDesShader, NULL, &m_pShaderResource ) );

D3D10_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC viewDesc;
ZeroMemory( &viewDesc, sizeof( viewDesc ) );
viewDesc.Format = texDesShader.Format;
viewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
viewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = texDesShader.MipLevels;
HR( m_Device->CreateShaderResourceView( m_pShaderResource, &viewDesc, &m_pShaderResourceView ) );
}

HRESULT COverlayTexture::Render(VOID)
{
m_Device->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, m_pShaderResourceView);

D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D lockedRect;
m_pStagingResource->Map( 0, D3D10_MAP_WRITE, 0, &lockedRect );

// Fill in the texture with the bitmap mapped from shared memory view

m_pStagingResource->Unmap(0);

m_Device->CopyResource(m_pShaderResource, m_pStagingResource); 
}
```

I use two instances of the class COverlayTexture each of which fills its own bitmap to its texture respectively and renders with sequence COverlayTexture[1] then COverlayTexture[0].

```
COverlayTexture* pOverlayTexture[2];

for( int i = 1; i < 0; i++)
{
     pOverlayTexture[i]->Render()
}
```

The blend state setting in the FX file is definedas below:

```
BlendState AlphaBlend
{
AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
BlendEnable[0] = TRUE;
      SrcBlend = SRC_ALPHA;
      DestBlend = INV_SRC_ALPHA;
      BlendOp = ADD;
      BlendOpAlpha = ADD;
      SrcBlendAlpha = ONE;
DestBlendAlpha = ZERO;
RenderTargetWriteMask[0] = 0x0f;
};
```

The pixel shader in the FX file is defined as below:

```
Texture2D txDiffuse;
float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
float4 ret = txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);
return ret;
}
```

Thanks again.

Edit for Paulo:

Thanks a lot, Paulo. The problem is that which instance of the object should be bound to alpha texture or diffuse texture. As testing, I bind the COverlayTexture[0] to the alpha and COverlayTexture[1] to the diffuse texture.

```
Texture2D txDiffuse[2];
float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
float4 ret = txDiffuse[1].Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);
float alpha = txDiffuse[0].Sample(samLinear, input.Tex).x;

return float4(ret.xyz, alpha);
}
```

I called the PSSetShaderResources for the two resource views.

```
g_pShaderResourceViews[0] = overlay[0].m_pShaderResourceView;
g_pShaderResourceViews[1] = overlay[1].m_pShaderResourceView;
m_Device->PSSetShaderResources(0, 2, g_pShaderResourceViews);
```

The result is that i don't see anything. I also tried the channel x,y,z,w.

Comment: Do you call `SetTexture` before drawing the other one ?

Comment: I assumed that it was the same as in DX9 but it seems to be a bit more complicated in DX10. No `SetTexture` for you as far as I can tell, check this out http://takinginitiative.net/2008/11/29/directx-10-tutorial-3-textures/

Answer (score 0):

Post some more code.

I'm not sure how you mean to mix these two textures. If you want to mix them in the pixel shader you need to sample both of them then add them (or whatever operation you required) toghether.

How do you add the textures toghether? By setting a ID3D11BlendState or in the pixel shader?

EDIT:

You don't need two textures in every class: if you want to write to your texture your usage should be D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC. When you do this, you can also have this texture as your shader resource so you don't need to do the `m_Device->CopyResource(m_pShaderResource, m_pStagingResource);` step.

Since you're using alpha blending you must control the alpha value output in the pixel shader (the w component of the float4 that the pixel shader returns).

Bind both textures to your pixel shader and use one textures value as the alpha components:

```
Texture2D txDiffuse;
Texture2D txAlpha;
float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 ret = txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);
    float alpha=txAlpha.Sample(samLinear,input.Tex).x; // Choose the proper channel
    return float4(ret.xyz,alpha); // Alpha is the 4th component
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect term to describe the issues. My current implementation is as below:

Comment: 1. Create texture[0] from CPU memory -> Fill texture[0] -> Create the resource view to bind to the pixel shader -> CopyResource from CPU memory to GPU memory.

Comment: 2. Create texture[1] from CPU memory -> Fill texture[1] -> Create the resource view to bind to the pixel shader -> CopyResource from CPU memory to GPU memory. 3. Call the Present. The pixel shader is mentioned as previous. I also call the ID3D11BlendState but it doesn't work. It looks that the texture[1] can't be bound to the pixel shader.

Comment: Should I do that in the pixel shader to have two textures and add them together?

Comment: As I said, post some code. Also note that you cannot bind a resource with the D3D10_USAGE_STAGING flags to the shader, so when you said you're doing a CopyResource you're probably creating another texture for both textures right?        If you need a simple blend you will probably get it done easier in the pixel shader imo since you can screw up the blend state settings easily and not get the result you want.

Comment: @Marshall: please add your code to your question, not to this answer.

Comment: Yes, I've added the code to the question. Please help take a look at again. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer, check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paulo. I tried the code but i can't see anything in game. I've added the code i wrote for your reference.

Comment: There is one thing bothering me about your code, but I'm not 100% sure: In the shader you declare your textures as Texture2D txDiffuse[2];, which is a texture array. I don't think you can do it this way without changing the flags while creating textures. So try declaring your textures in the shader as I did: Texture2D txDiffuse;
Texture2D txAlpha; Use pix to make sure that both are bind so that the textures are ok.